# No option of open cmd here or open Powershell window here on right click

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, terminal

My problem basically is that after I have installed git bash on my system, the option `Open command window here` and `Open PowerShell window here` does not appear.

[image]

So from somewhere, I got to know that `shift`+ right-click should show me an option to open Powershell, and it really worked, but now I want to run this Powershell as an administrator, and now I have no option like that even after doing `shift` + right-click.

Here a screen shot of that

[image]

So here is what I want:

1. I should get an option to open cmd and PowerShell only by doing a right click as it used to happen before I downloaded git.
2. I should also get an option to run them as an administrator only by doing a right-click.

It would be great if anybody could help me to overcome this problem as fast as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe you're asking on the wrong site. Super User should be a place you should ask this, not a programming site. Although, you can try *Ctrl* + *Shift* + *Left Click*. It's how I use to open my ise, to include *Shift* + *F10* for the settings menu of it.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I was unaware of this site. Thanks for letting me know about this. Would surely post such questions over there from now onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is by adding registry entries manually.
Here is a link for a detailed tutorials:

[Add or Remove 'Open PowerShell window here' context menu](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/60175-open-powershell-window-here-context-menu-add-windows-10-a.html)

[Open command window here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72024-open-command-window-here-add-windows-10-a.html)

[Open command window here as administrator](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/59686-open-command-window-here-administrator-add-windows-10-a.html)

[Open PowerShell window here as administrator](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/60177-add-open-powershell-window-here-administrator-windows-10-a.html)

these links include solution for both right click or shift + right click

If you find this helpful please rate up so I get some +rep (because I am new)

Comment: @Rosie Thanks for giving an answer to my question. I am unable to find options to add `open with cmd`, and options to open both cmd and terminal as an administrator in the article you provided.

Comment: Let me just experiment with the method provided in this article and find if I can satisfy my other needs also through this method in any way. I would surely select this as the best answer after I am able to satisfy those needs also through this method. But still, I have liked this answer for you showed interest to help me out and solved some part of my problem. Thanks again

Comment: thank you ^^
and sorry for the lacking answer. I have edited it.